# FILESTREAM - Reading documents stored in the File System using SQLFileStream

Tags: c#, filestream

I saved Filestream documents in the NTFS. Each time I attempt to access them using the block below, I get the 'Parameter Is Not Valid' error message on the Image.FromStream line. Would this have anything to do with the stored files in the FS folder? Or are my parameters missing something?
Is there a way to view the files in the folder to verify they are well formed?

```
private static Image LoadPhotoImage(string filePath, byte[] txnToken)
    {
        Image photo;
        try
        {
            using (SqlFileStream sfs =
              new SqlFileStream(filePath, txnToken, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                photo = Image.FromStream(sfs,false);
                sfs.Close();
            }

            return photo;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ae)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ae.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I saved Filestream documents in the NTFS"?  It *almost* sounds like you pulled your documents out of sql server and stored them somewhere else and now want to use the SqlFileStream object...

Comment: Is the stream empty if you debug your code? does the stream really contain an image that can be read by GDI?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use SqlFileStream for this purpose, per the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream.aspx):

"The SqlFileStream class is used to work with varbinary(max) data stored with the FILESTREAM attribute in a SQL Server 2008 database."

Just use Image.FromFile to load the image.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.  If the SqlFileStream isn't to be used to load a file stored in a sql server file stream, then what is it for?

Comment: @Chris Lively: The OP stated that they were reading the file from the NTFS (i.e. the windows file system), not SQL Server.

Comment: @competent_tech I've used the `SqlFileStream` very much like the OP is doing, it is valid. Also the filePath is from the Database perspective, so `Image.FromFile` might not work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guys. I loaded documents(pdf, .docs, and image files) from the client machine onto SQL Server. Because I enabled Filestream, I have the data stored not in the db but in the NTFS. I can see the folders in my file system. What I now need is a way to retrieve them and view them on a usercontrol.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you could edit your question to include the call to LoadPhotoImage so we know exactly what you are doing to get the path? If you are doing something like the ADO.Net example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724.aspx, then I need to revise my answer.

Comment: To save my files, I got RadUpload to call the service using a modification of the code from : http://blog.tallan.com/2011/08/22/using-sqlfilestream-with-c-to-access-sql-server-filestream-data/

Comment: To retrieve the files i use the following         private void hypDocument_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            var thisDoc = (sender as HyperlinkButton).DataContext as QualificationDocument;
            
            wc.OpenReadCompleted +=new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);
            Uri u = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, "../SelectFileStreamDoc.ashx/?documentID=" + thisDoc.DocumentID);
            wc.OpenReadAsync(u);
        }